# Developing proper algorithm for numeric combination

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello to all experts in Excel formula programming and mathematicians.
I am trying to develop a formula applicable in Excel that generates possible combinations of 7 numbers within number span from 1 to 50.
Interesting here is that I can`t find a proper way how to fully integrate all needed variables in same formula for expected result.

Following variables I am trying to integrate are these:

1. numbers can be formed from 1 and 2 digits
2. number span to form combination of numbers is from 1 - 50
3. each combination contains 7 different numbers (without repeating inside same combination)
4. numbers should be lined in order from smallest to highest value if possible
5. to simplify (reduce) from all possible combinations, it is crucial that combinations can be generated from "**manually inserted**" chosen numbers (they are within this same numeric span of 1 - 50). This is what I think is most challenging how to create.
6. alternatively, is it possible to integrate in this kind of formula a loop that checks or blocks that same combination of set of 7 numbers are repeated within all combinations? This is to prevent repeating of same set of combination of numbers within ultimate possible of combinations following these all previous conditions.

Thank you for support,
DucyD

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a complete solution.**

But it will list the first 1,000,000 combinations *(the total number would be around 99,884,401)*:

```
Sub kombo()
    Z = 1
    For a = 1 To 50 - 6
        For b = a + 1 To 50 - 5
            For c = b + 1 To 50 - 4
                For d = c + 1 To 50 - 3
                    For e = d + 1 To 50 - 2
                        For f = e + 1 To 50 - 1
                            For g = f + 1 To 50
                                Cells(Z, 1) = a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & "," & e & "," & f & "," & g
                                Z = Z + 1
                                If Z = 1000000 Then Exit Sub
                            Next g
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub
```

Near the top:

[image]

At the bottom:

[image]

Comment: If you had a "full list", you could use an `AGGREGATE`-based function to pull ones that match the "must have" numbers.  But, Excel won't let you have that many row merely 1,048,576 of them

Answer (score 0):

User defined function that accepts a comma an array of comma delimited numbers and generates a combination is within the first five parameters described in OP. The last parameter greatly complicates the problem, do you expect to get collisions? Are you planning on generating a million sets of combinations, fifty, a hundred thousand? You can pass the range that you want to check to CombinationGenerator and check. See bottom of post for an idea as to handle this parameter.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CombinationGenerator(Optional ByRef valueString As String) As String
    Dim rndNum          As Long
    Dim indexI          As Long
    Dim indexII         As Long
    Dim doubleValuePass As Boolean
    Dim tempStr         As String
    Dim position        As Long
    Dim values()        As String
    Dim shuffled(7)     As String

    values = Split(valueString, ",")
    ReDim Preserve values(7)

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(values)
        If values(indexI) = "" Then
            Randomize
            rndNum = Int(Rnd * 50) + 1
            values(indexI) = CStr(rndNum)
            Do Until doubleValuePass = True
                doubleValuePass = True
                For indexII = 0 To UBound(values)
                    If (values(indexI) = values(indexII)) And (indexI <> indexII) Then
                        doubleValuePass = False
                        Randomize
                        rndNum = Int(Rnd * 50) + 1
                        values(indexI) = CStr(rndNum)
                    End If
                Next indexII
            Loop
            doubleValuePass = False
        End If
    Next indexI

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(values)
        position = 0
        For indexII = 0 To UBound(values)
            If CInt(values(indexI)) > CInt(values(indexII)) Then position = position + 1
        Next indexII
        shuffled(position) = values(indexI)
    Next indexI

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(shuffled)
        tempStr = tempStr + "," + shuffled(indexI)
    Next indexI

    tempStr = Right(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - 1)
    CombinationGenerator = tempStr
End Function
```

[image]

This breaks the functions out. The last function, to check that your generated string does not exist in a range that you have passed to the first function, really depends on expected use.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CombinationGenerator(Optional ByRef valueString As String, Optional ByRef rng As Range) As String
    Dim tempStr         As String
    Dim position        As Long
    Dim inputValues()   As String
    Dim combination()   As String

    inputValues = Split(valueString, ",")
    ReDim Preserve inputValues(7)
    combination = CombinationGenerate(inputValues)
    combination = CombinationShuffle(combination)
    tempStr = CombinationToString(combination)
    tempStr = CombinationNotInRange(tempStr)
    CombinationGenerator = tempStr
End Function

Private Function CombinationGenerate(ByRef combination() As String) As String()
    Dim indexI          As Long
    Dim indexII         As Long
    Dim rndNum          As Long
    Dim doubleValuePass As Boolean

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(combination)
        If combination(indexI) = "" Then
            Randomize
            rndNum = Int(Rnd * 50) + 1
            combination(indexI) = CStr(rndNum)
            Do Until doubleValuePass = True
                doubleValuePass = True
                For indexII = 0 To UBound(combination)
                    If (combination(indexI) = combination(indexII)) And (indexI <> indexII) Then
                        doubleValuePass = False
                        Randomize
                        rndNum = Int(Rnd * 50) + 1
                        combination(indexI) = CStr(rndNum)
                    End If
                Next indexII
            Loop
            doubleValuePass = False
        End If
    Next indexI
    CombinationGenerate = combination
End Function

Private Function CombinationShuffle(ByRef combination() As String) As String()
    Dim indexI          As Long
    Dim indexII         As Long
    Dim position        As Long
    Dim shuffled(7)     As String

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(combination)
        position = 0
        For indexII = 0 To UBound(combination)
            If CInt(combination(indexI)) > CInt(combination(indexII)) Then position = position + 1
        Next indexII
        shuffled(position) = combination(indexI)
    Next indexI
    CombinationShuffle = shuffled
End Function

Private Function CombinationToString(ByRef shuffledCombination() As String) As String
    Dim indexI          As Long
    Dim tempStr         As String

    For indexI = 0 To UBound(shuffledCombination)
        tempStr = tempStr + "," + shuffledCombination(indexI)
    Next indexI
    tempStr = Right(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - 1)
    CombinationToString = tempStr
End Function

Private Function CombinationNotInRange(ByRef combination As String, Optional ByRef rngToCheck As Range) As String
    'Depends
    CombinationNotInRange = combination
End Function
```